# Hide a Drop-down list if an other drop-down list has a selected value

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, c#-4.0

I have two drop-down lists,
My task is to hide one of the drop-down lists.
If the user chooses a value in drop-down list 1 I need to hide the drop-down list 2 and vice-versa.

```
 @if (Model.DeputyId == null)
                        {
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>@Html.DrawLabel("PoliticalGroup")</label>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PoliticalGroupId, Model.PoliticalGroups, @Html.DrawLabel("SelectAPoliticalGroup"), new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                        }
                        @if (Model.PoliticalGroupId == null)
                        {
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>@Html.DrawLabel("Deputy")</label>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DeputyId, Model.Deputies, @Html.DrawLabel("SelectADeputy"), new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                        }
```

These are the two drop-down lists that I need to control which one is shown and which one is hidden based on user selection.
Thank you for your time

Comment: Are you willing to use client-side JS? I think you can handle `onchange` event from first DDLF and use `hide()` method for second DDLF.

Comment: Yes that's a good idea, and jQuery would be even better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    
    $('.target').on('change', function () {
     if ($(".target").children()[1].selected)
        {
            $(".target1").show();
            $(".target2").hide();
            $(".ddl1").val("");
        }
     else if ($(".target").children()[2].selected)
        {
            $(".target2").show();
            $(".target1").hide();
            $(".ddl2").val("");
        }

    });
});
```

This is a potential solution for this problem.
Other than this I just added some classes in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

- give same class to both dropdown (in this case "ddl")

  ```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.A3, new SelectList(Model.lstManager3, "Value", "Text", Model.A3), "Select", new { @class = "ddl form-control" })

  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.A4, new SelectList(Model.lstManager4, "Value", "Text", Model.A4), "Select", new { @class = "ddl form-control" })
  ```

## jquery code

```
    var className = '.ddl';
    var defaultDdl1Text = 'SelectAPoliticalGroup';
    var defaultDdl2Text = 'SelectADeputy';


     $(className).change(function () {
        var Value = this.value;
        var Text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        if (Text != defaultDdl1Text && Text != defaultDdl2Text) {
            $(className).not(this).hide();
        }
        else {
            $(className).not(this).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: hard coded options are not allowed in my project so this var values can't be used